# Исползование ответа сервера в C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Написал запрос к серверу на Javascript ответ нормально возврашется через `respMessage`

```js
function commandResult()   
{                                
(function(callback)                
{                      
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();                         
 xhttp.open("POST", 'http://127.0.0.1:11005/scan/', true);                    
 xhttp.send("1");                                    
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()                                                         
 {                                                                            
 if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)                                                         
 {                                           
 callback(xhttp.responseText);             
 }                                  
 };                                                        
 })(function(respMessage)                   
 {                            
 var xhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();    
 xhttp1.open("POST", 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':11006/myScan/', true);   
 xhttp1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');       
 xhttp1.send(JSON.stringify(respMessage));                      
 xhttp1.onreadystatechange = function()         
 {                                            
 if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)     
 console.log(this);                               
 };                      
 })   
 }
```

Как исползовать этот ответ в коде C#, или как вообще получить ответ в коде C#?  Программа работатет в системе AcumaticaERP.
Это код на C# которое принимает ответ сервера

```
    private static byte[] imageByte ;
    private NetWorker _netWorker ;
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        _netWorker = new XhtListener(new[] {  "http://localhost:11006/myScan/" });
    }
    public PXAction<SOShipment> MyButton;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Smart Popup", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Enabled = false)]
    protected void myButton()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = MyPanel.AskExt();
            switch (result)
            {
                case WebDialogResult.OK:
                    {
                        _netWorker.Start();
                       ////
                      ////                         
                        break;
                    }
                case WebDialogResult.Cancel:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }
    }
    public abstract class NetWorker
    {
        public bool WorkFlag;
        public abstract void Stop();
        public abstract void Start();
        public abstract void Close();
    }
    public class XhtListener : NetWorker
    {
        private HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        public XhtListener(IReadOnlyCollection<string> prefixes)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            {
                ////
                return;
            }
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Count == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");
            foreach (var s in prefixes)
            {
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
            }
        }
        public override void Start()
           {
                if (!WorkFlag)
                {
                    WorkFlag = true;
                }

                var tr = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (WorkFlag)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _listener.Start();
                            // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request.
                            if (!_listener.IsListening) continue;
                            HttpListenerContext context;
                            context = _listener.GetContext();
                            using (var read = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
                            {
                                string str = read.ReadToEnd();
                                var base64Data = Regex.Match(str, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
                                var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
                                imageByte = new byte[1000]; 
                                imageByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(binData.ToString());
                            }
                            WorkFlag = false;
                            Close();      
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                           //
                        }
                    }
                });
                tr.Start();
          }
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, ты хочешь полученный ответ отправлять в стороннее приложение. А что есть C#? Каким образом он связан с этим js?

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz  поправил вопрос код добавил к вопросу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку ответа пока что нету и что бы так и не остаться я сам отвечу свой вопрос!
По началу добавил `delegete` в мой класс `DSPNetWorker`

```
public delegate void MySaveDel(byte[] b);//добовленный делегат
public abstract class DSPNetWorker
{
  public MySaveDel msd;
  public bool WorkFlag;
  public abstract void Stop();
  public abstract void Start();
  public abstract void Close();
}
```

После чего с помощю делегата получил взял ответ получённый от сервера!

```
public class DSPXhtListener : DSPNetWorker
{
  private HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();    
  public IIG_DSPXhtListener(IReadOnlyCollection<string> prefixes)
  {
      if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
      {
          IIG_DSPLogger.WriteLog("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required 
           to use the HttpListener class.", LoggingLevel.Error);
          return;
      }
      // URI prefixes are required,
      // for example "http://contoso.com:8080/index/".
      if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Count == 0)
      {
          throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");
      }
      // Add the prefixes.
      foreach (var s in prefixes)
      {
          _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
      }
  }
  public override void Start()
  {
      try
      {
          _listener.Start();
          if (!_listener.IsListening)
          {
              IIG_DSPLogger.WriteLog("Listener was not created", LoggingLevel.Error);
          }
          HttpListenerContext context;
          context = _listener.GetContext();
          var resp = context.Response;
          var respStream = resp.OutputStream;
          resp.ContentType = "text/plain";
          resp.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          using (var read = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
          {
              string str = read.ReadToEnd();
              str = str.Substring(2, str.Length - 4);
              var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
              msd(binData);//**Вот здесь получаю ответ сервера**
          }
          var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Ok"));
          respStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
          respStream.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          IIG_DSPLogger.WriteLog(ex.Message, LoggingLevel.Error);
      }
  }
  public override void Stop()
  {
      WorkFlag = false;
  }
  public override void Close()
  {
      try
      {
          _listener.Stop();
          _listener.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception exc)
      {
          IIG_DSPLogger.WriteLog(exc.Message, LoggingLevel.Error);
      }
  }
```

И вот так использовал ответ!

```
 private readonly DSPNetWorker _netWorker = new DSPXhtListener(new[] { "http://*:11006/myScan/" });
  public override void Initialize()
  {
      _netWorker.msd = SaveImageDel<APInvoice>;
  }
```

Где `SaveImageDel<APInvoice>` функция которая исползует этот ответ.